# Question about running python in QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, python-3, idle

I have 5 python scripts in the following folders :

- .\Signal_Slot_Example\main.py
- .\Signal_Slot_Example\ProgressDialog\init.py
- .\Signal_Slot_Example\ProgressDialog\Progress.py
- .\Signal_Slot_Example\SliderDialog\init.py
- .\Signal_Slot_Example\SliderDialog\Slider.py

Main.py when run calls the other 2 scripts and creates a simple slid that interacts with a progress bar and when I run it in Idle it all works fine.

When I run it in the QGIS python console I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SliderDialog'
```

Why won't it work in QGIS but runs fine in Idle ?

All the example code I have run in QGIS python console and in idle worked the same the only difference here is that I am calling classes from other .py scripts.

Answer (score 1):

In your **Signal_Slot_Example.main.py** file, if you import local modules, try to add a dot before the name of the module :

```
import .SliderDialog
```

Comment: Throws an invalid syntax; the way I have the question might be confusing the "." are not actually in the file name it was my way of trying to show where the files were in the directory structure. Maybe I should have used arrows...

Comment: Can you edit your original post to update the directories / files format ?

Comment: I think that is better, do note that the init.py files are actually __init__.py is just that the __ disappear in the text block for some reason.

Comment: try `import .SliderDialog.init`

Comment: That isn't working either; from what I can tell it seems like it isn't finding the file in that path, is there a way to put in the full path?

Comment: For get the current working directory : `import os` and in the code `print(os.getcwd())`.

Comment: When I run it in QGIS I get C:\OSGEO4~1\bin printed as the directory
When I run it in Idle I get C:\Users\tveinot\Signal_Slot_Example printed as the directory so I need a bit of code to set the workspace I think.

Comment: I added os.chdir('C:\\...\\Signal_Slot_Example\\') but it didn't change anything

Comment: In the beginning of the script, must be `import os` followed by `os.chdir ...` and after other modules import. Hope that help.

Comment: I added import sys, import PyQt5, os.chdir(MyDir), sys.pth.insert(0,r'MyDir') then from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog. The error went away and the dir prints in the console but no sliders pop up. I also tried rearranging it as suggested and the error goes away and the dir prints but still no slide bar or progress bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91997/discussion-between-tyler-veinot-and-j-monticolo).